# Unable to understand IIFE and scope in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code snippet below

```
(async () => {
    const app = express();
    let test = "test string";

    app.get('/numbers', (req, res) => {
        res.send(test);
    }

    app.listen( 8000, () => {
      console.log( `server running http://localhost:8000`);
    });
)();
```

If I run the above code snippet, the server starts listening on localhost:8000.  

How is that working? 
How am I able to access `test` variable in my `get` method? Wouldn't the `test` variable be destroyed once the topmost function has finished executing?

Comment: Why would the server _stop_ when `app` goes out of scope?

Comment: well, You create the function's scope => app listens for port 8000 (in that scope) - what's the problem ..?

Comment: Why is the code in an async function?

Comment: @tkausl shouldn't the server stop once app goes out of scope because we are "listening" on app?

Comment: @Vovan_Super once the function finishes executing, `app` goes out of scope, right? So the server should also stop, right?

Comment: Who's `we`? `listen` is just a function.

Comment: @AnkitArora, the `app` (block-scoped variable (rather const)  You've created with `const app = express();` doesn't leave the scope created by the  iife ..

Comment: @tkausl I have updated the code snippet to include a more valid example.

Comment: @Vovan_Super I have updated the code snippet to include a more valid example.

Comment: `Wouldn't the test variable be destroyed once the topmost function has finished executing?` No, the unnamed arrow function passed to `get` keeps it alive. This is just how scopes in JS work, nothing new.

Comment: *"Wouldn't the test variable be destroyed once the topmost function has finished executing?"* No, because the functions are closures.

Comment: @AnkitArora, there's another 'example' ( express server starts in a scope): https://github.com/VovanSuper/MERN-dummy/blob/main/server/index.js#L41 - .. it's how Javascript works (function creates scope -> it's not destroyed when js-vm finishes to execute that function ...